# Xcode 4.5 (iOS 6) getting conflicting types error?

Tags: c++, xcode4.5

I am using this code in a file `inet_ntop.h`. Here I declared `const char *inet_ntop`.

```
#ifndef HAVE_INET_NTOP
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif
    const char *inet_ntop(int af, const void *src, char *dst, size_t size);
#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
#endif /* HAVE_INET_NTOP */
```

At compile time, I am getting a "conflicting types for `inet_ntop`" error.

This is working in Xcode 3.2.3, but using the code in the same application in Xcode 4.5 gives me this conflicting error. How do I fix this?

Comment: where do you get conflict type? example?

Comment: Are you including `<arpa/inet.h>`? It's the file that usually have this prototype. Also, as you can see from the [official POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_ntop.html) you have the type of the last argument wrong.

Comment: Conflicting types for 'inet_ntop' I ma getting error in above code.

Comment: And when i change Xcode Compiler C/C++: LLVM GCC 4.2 i am getting conflicting types for 'sprintf' in stdio.h

Comment: Hi alexwlchan, I am expecting answer for question not for correction ... try to help some one